# Android ListView positioning for TextView

Tags: android, listview, textview, position, dialog

I don't really know where to begin asking this question, so I'll just try to describe my problem the best I can...I'm currently working on a ListView with a custom List Adapter that inflates 2 text Views and a checkBox. One textView is a description of the option, where the other textView is saved for when I need to use it to display data. When a user clicks on an item in the List it will pop up with an editText Dialog box. I got it to save the text and display it, but the problem I'm having is that when it displays the data, it's not on the correct ListView item... for example: http://www.vbsteven.be/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/screenshotcalllog.png
Say if I wanted to display the information I got from my dialog box in the first slot of the listView. It displays randomly in either the 3rd 2nd or 4th positions. This seems like such a simple problem but I've been struggling for a while...

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/rowTextView" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
  </TextView>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/alarm_name_text" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:text="" 
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rowTextView" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent">
   </TextView>

  <CheckBox android:id="@+id/CheckBox01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
    android:focusable="false">
  </CheckBox>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity:

```
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY:

            LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            final View textEntryView = mInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.alert_text_entry, null);
            /*final View textEntryView1 = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);*/
            final EditText savedText = ((EditText)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.password_edit));
            final TextView rowSavedText = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.alarm_name_text));
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(AlarmList.this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_icon)
                    .setTitle("Enter your name")
                    .setView(textEntryView)
                    .setPositiveButton("accept",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    String temp = savedText.getText().toString();
                                    rowSavedText.setText(temp);
                                    rowSavedText.setVisibility(0);
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    }).create();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

If anyone wants to see any other part of my code for helping, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Heres my list Adapter and data in it :

```
planets = new Planet[] { new Planet("Turn On Alarm"),
                    new Planet("Alarm Name"), new Planet("Time"),
                    new Planet("Sound"), new Planet("Vibrate"),
                    new Planet("Repeat"), new Planet("Volume Control"),
                    new Planet("Second Alarm") };
        }
        ArrayList<Planet> planetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        planetList.addAll(Arrays.asList(planets));


listAdapter = new PlanetArrayAdapter(this, planetList);
```

/** Custom adapter for displaying an array of Planet objects. */
    private class PlanetArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public PlanetArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Planet> planetList) {
        super(context, R.layout.row, R.id.rowTextView, planetList);

        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Planet to display
        Planet planet = (Planet) this.getItem(position);


        // The child views in each row.
        CheckBox checkBox;
        TextView textView;
        Spinner mySpinner;


// Create a new row view
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

                // Find the child views.
                textView = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
                checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);
                // Optimization: Tag the row with it's child views, so we don't
                // have to
                // call findViewById() later when we reuse the row.
                convertView.setTag(new PlanetViewHolder(textView, checkBox));

                // If CheckBox is toggled, update the planet it is tagged with.
                checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                        Planet planet = (Planet) cb.getTag();
                        planet.setChecked(cb.isChecked());
                    }
                });
            }
            // Reuse existing row view
            else {
                // Because we use a ViewHolder, we avoid having to call
                // findViewById().
                PlanetViewHolder viewHolder = (PlanetViewHolder) convertView
                        .getTag();
                checkBox = viewHolder.getCheckBox();
                textView = viewHolder.getTextView();
            }

            // Tag the CheckBox with the Planet it is displaying, so that we can
            // access the planet in onClick() when the CheckBox is toggled.
            checkBox.setTag(planet);

            // Display planet data
            checkBox.setChecked(planet.isChecked());
            textView.setText(planet.getName());

            return convertView;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you can set those textviews from the dialog view. You will have to set them from within your custom list adapter. Get the name from dialog like you are doing, then add the name to your custom adapter's data set and finally set the adapter again or notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. If how can I get the name from the dialogView, then use it outside of the scope? Also, am I supposed to set my TextViews in the getView() method? and when I add the data set, am I passing it in? or just defining a piece of data.. Sorry, I'm very new to android and we don't have any teachers at my college.

Comment: Get the text from the dialog, then add it in your ArrayList or whatever structure you use for your Adapter, when you add it, call YourCursor.notifyDataSetChanged(), then the cursor will repopulate the listview and have the data from the dialog placed in your listview. Don't forget to call YourCursor.notifyDataSetInvalidated(); which will cause the listview to redraw itself including new data.

 I bet this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: is there any way to talk in chat? What you're saying is actually making sense, I'm just not sure how to add that String.

Comment: I mean, the text is getting stored and put into a textView on one of the ListView Views. Just not the CORRECT view...

Comment: Listview is more than one view. It is like a stack of views. when you call rowSavedText.setText(temp) from the dialog, it sets it on whatever view the adapter is drawing/setting at that time. That's why you have to make the change on the arraylist/adapter and then have it repopulate listview. Can you post your custom list adapter?